# How i can use variable in string?

Tags: javascript

I have problem with template strings. I created a variable, but i can't put it in string

```
let suffix = "-dev";
alert("hello, ${suffix}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use template strings you have to use backticks ( `` ).

```js
let suffix = "-dev";
alert(`hello, ${suffix}`);
```